# Orientation change increases TextView's text size

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, textview, text-size

I want to save my current text size by `SharedPreferences`, and set it back when screen orientation is changed.

I use this code, but when I change the screen orientation it makes the `textSize` bigger...

```
package com.example.zz;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView text;
    float size;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    private final String TEXT_SIZE = "textsize";
    final String MyPref = "preference";
    SharedPreferences settings;
    Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        settings = this.getSharedPreferences(MyPref, 0);
        text.setTextSize(settings.getFloat(TEXT_SIZE, 0));
        editor = settings.edit();
    }

    public void sizeUp(MenuItem item) {
        size = text.getTextSize();
        text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, (float) (size + 5));

    }

    public void sizeDown(MenuItem item) {
        size = text.getTextSize();
        text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, (float) (size - 5));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putFloat(TEXT_SIZE, text.getTextSize());

        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method [getTextSize()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getTextSize()) returns text size in *pixels*, but [setTextSize()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize(float)) treats the size in *sp* units. That's why your text looks bigger. You should scale the size before using in `setTextSize()`. You can do like this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putFloat(TEXT_SIZE, text.getTextSize()/getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity); // put text size in sp
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I did't find onConfigure chnage method in this code,

You have to implement this method, and changes text size in this method.

```
    @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(MyPref, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putFloat(TEXT_SIZE, text.getTextSize());

        editor.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this by code, you can use styles for this.

First, set the style of your `TextView` in `styles.xml` with nthe desired text size for portrait mode. For example:

```
<style name="MyTextView">
   <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

Then, create a folder `values-land` in the `res` folder and put a `styles.xml` file in this folder and create a style with the same name but a different value for text size:

```
<style name="MyTextView">
   <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
</style>
```

Finally, apply this style to your `TextView` in your layout and the text size will automaticall change according to the phones orientation. Extra benifit is that it's very easy to maintain/change the look of your views this way.

Edit: changed textsize in dp to sp

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (picUri != null) {
    // here you store string    
        outState.putString("cameraImageUri", picUri.toString());


    }


}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("cameraImageUri")) {
           // here you get string again
        picUri = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("cameraImageUri"));
    }


}
```